# For each loop is not getting executed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the below code but it doesnot execute the for each loop fully

A class :

```
if (errorILevel)
  return;
else
{
  int z = await _valuationManagement.UpdateLastILevelRefreshTimeForPDFAll(valuationFundTemplates, cancellationToken);
}
```

B Class :

```
public async Task<int> UpdateLastILevelRefreshTimeForPDFAll(List<ValuationFundTemplateWithPortfolioCompany> valuationFundTemplate, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
  int result = await _valuationFundTemplateRepository.UpdateLastRefreshILevelPDFAll(valuationFundTemplate,cancellationToken);
  return result;
}
```

C Class :

```
public async Task<int> UpdateLastRefreshILevelPDFAll(List<ValuationFundTemplateWithPortfolioCompany> valuationFundTemplate, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
  foreach (var item in valuationFundTemplate)
  {
    var tempTemplates = await _context.ValuationFundTemplate.SingleAsync(p => p.ValuationId == item.ValuationId && p.FundId == item.FundId && p.TemplateId == item.TemplateId, cancellationToken);
    tempTemplates.LastILevelRefreshTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  }
  return await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

As soon as

```
var tempTemplates = await _context.ValuationFundTemplate.SingleAsync(p => 
    p.ValuationId == item.ValuationId && p.FundId == item.FundId &&
    p.TemplateId == item.TemplateId, cancellationToken);
```

is executed it goes back to the B class and B class goes back to A class without returning any result.  It does not even execute the for each loop . Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: @MichaelRandall it is just part of the code that i am showing here

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on this line `tempTemplates.LastILevelRefreshTime = DateTime.UtcNow` and see if it ever breaks there.  If not, put a breakpoint on your `foreach` an dcheck to see if there's anything in `valuationFundTemplate`

Comment: @Flydog57 it doesnot come to the line tempTemplates.LastILevelRefreshTime = DateTime.UtcNow. As soon as it hits var tempTemplates = await _context.ValuationFundTemplate.SingleAsync(p => p.ValuationId == item.ValuationId && p.FundId == item.FundId && p.TemplateId == item.TemplateId, cancellationToken); it breaks

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an await some where...

Comment: @johnny5 i have added await everywhere as you can see in the code

Comment: Yeah I saw you're not missing one here, but I can't think of another the debugger would step out.

Comment: it sounds like that or the cancellation token is being invoked, and that would trigger if you closed the web page (Or if you were missing an await and you returned the response before the method had time to complete)

Comment: De-*async* your `SingleAsync` call (i.e., call `Single` without the `await`) and see what happens.  Is there anything in your collection that matches the criteria?

Comment: Hi i am gettint this error Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ValuationsReportingContext'.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are getting an error at

```
_context.ValuationFundTemplate.SingleAsync
```

That's why everything returns right away. You can verify by wrapping the call in a try catch block, and place a breakpoint in the catch block

Comment: you are right i am getting error here 
Error : Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ValuationsReportingContext'.

Comment: That means you opened and disposed the _context somewhere before. You can try the suggested statement: don't dispose and don't use "using" statement